# SQL Azure Profiling

Tags: azure, profiling, azure-sql-database, profiler

I read on the MS site that SQL Azure does not support SQL Profiler. What are people using to profile queries running on this platform?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I haven't got too far playing around with SQL Azure as yet, but from what I understand there isn't anything you can use at the moment.

[From MS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-technical-overview/) (probably the article you read):

> Because SQL Azure performs the
>   physical administration, any
>   statements and options that attempt to
>   directly manipulate physical resources
>   will be blocked, such as Resource
>   Governor, file group references, and
>   some physical server DDL statements.
>   It is also not possible to set server
>   options and SQL trace flags or use the
>   SQL Server Profiler or the Database
>   Tuning Advisor utilities.

If there were to be an alernative, I'd imagine it would require the ability to set trace flags which you can't do, hence I don't think there is an option at the moment.

Solution? I can only suggest you have a local development copy of the db so you can run profiler locally on it. I know that won't help with "live" issues/debugging/monitoring but it depends on what you need it for.

**Edit:**
Quote from [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/6514c399-079d-451b-ae2d-59763c8cfb54):

> Q: Is SQL Profiler supported in SQL
>   Azure?
>
> A: We do not support SQL Profiler in
>   v1 of SQL Azure.

Now, you could interpret that as a hint that Profiler will be supported in future versions. I think it will be a big requirement to get a lot of people on board, using SQL Azure seriously.

Comment: According to this following link, it will be a feature, but no release date has yet to be announced. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/fd128986-694b-421a-a863-44623590a144/

Comment: This must be very out of date, but it's the  #2 hit on google. Ada can you update it (it it's wrong)?

Answer (score 18):

**Update as of 9/17/2015:**

Microsoft just announced a new feature called [Index Advisor](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/optimize-database-performance-using-index-advisor-7/):

> How does Index Advisor work? Index Advisor continuously monitors your
>   database workload, performs the analysis and recommends new indexes
>   that can further improve the DB performance.
>
> Recommendations are always kept up-to-date: As the DB workload and
>   schema evolves, Index Advisor will monitor the changes and adjust the
>   recommendations accordingly. Each recommendation comes with the
>   estimated impact to DB workload performance: You can use this
>   information to prioritize the most impactful recommendations first. In
>   addition, Index Advisor provides a very easy and powerful way of
>   creating the recommended indexes.
>
> Creating new indexes only takes a couple of clicks. Index Advisor
>   measures the impact of newly created indexes and provides a report on
>   index impact to users. You can get started with Index Advisor and
>   improve your database performance with the following simple steps. It
>   literally takes five minutes to get accustomed with Index Advisor’s
>   simple and intuitive user interface. Let’s get started!

**Original Answer:**

SQL Azure now has some native profiling.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benko/archive/2012/05/19/cloudtip-14-how-do-i-get-sql-profiler-info-from-sql-azure.aspx for details.

Comment: This does not seem to show you the incoming stored procedures calls, only the most expensive ones run in the past?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft's stated position SQL Server Profiler is deprecated. As much as this is a bad idea, [that's what they have said](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/431943-profiler-for-sql-azure).

> SQL Profile is already deprecated in SQL Server, and that’s part of
>   the reason that it doesn’t make sense to bring to SQL DB.

What this means is you are going back 20+ years in database performance monitoring and everyone is going to have to write their own perf monitoring scripts instead of having a standard factory delivered tool that's on every server you will go to. It's tantamount to deprecating "sp_help" and making every DBA write their own. Hope you know all your DMVs inside and out... INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, and CROSS APPLY syntax really well.

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question; they asked what to use as an alternative.

Comment: Using traditional tools, which he's referring to (SQL Profiler), you can't. Which is exactly the answer to his question. Profiler gives you REAL TIME access to the database kernel. DMVs are anything from permanent to transient depending on memory pressure... and it varies by DMV. For example, virtual filestats is permanent. Worst running queries are not. So yes, I did answer the question. The "solution" that MSFT is offering-- go Google the internet and hope someone else has figured this out for you because we're eliminating the standard tool that has been used for well over 15 years.

Comment: Sounds like that time when the brilliant engineers at Microsoft decided that the Windows Start button can be deprecated because the couldn't figure out with their infinite wisdom that some (or most) users are relying on it.

Answer (score 4):

**Update as of 2017/04/14:**

Microsoft's Scott Guthrie  today announced a lot of new features in SQLAzure(this is  called sqlazure managed instance,which is currently in preview),which are expected to be present in SQLAzure in coming months..below are them

1.SQLAgent
2.SQLProfiler
3.SQLCLR
4.Service Broker
5.Logshipping,Transactional Replication
6.Native/Backup restore
7.Additional DMV's and Xevents
8.cross database querying

**References:**
https://youtu.be/0uT46lpjeQE?t=1415

Comment: Good update, but the answer to this question is really [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-xevent-db-diff-from-svr).  I'm surprised to see it missing from the five answers on this post!?

Answer (score 4):

I have tried today a new tool suggested by Microsoft that is called [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio).

In this tool you can download an extension called [Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension) and it seems to be working just as expected.

Comment: I've used it. It doesn't have quite the same level of configuration, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Query store feature, look here for more details: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/06/08/query-store-a-flight-data-recorder-for-your-database/

Comment: Do you perhaps know of azure profiler and can take a look at this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383539/azure-profiler-session-does-not-appear-in-app-insight/

Answer (score 0):

The most close to SQL profiler, that I found working in Azure SQL, is [SQL Workload Profiler](https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/sql-workload-profiler/)
However note, that it’s beta version of a tool, created but a single person, and it is not too convinient to use.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure offers following features to tune performance, profile queries in its own way, identity long running queries and much more

Intelligent Performance
  Performance overview
  Performance recommendations
  Query Performance Insight
  Automatic tuning