# Is there a way to log/trace all SQL queries made from a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-sql-database

I'm working on a WCF service and I'd like to be able to get a dump of all the SQL queries it makes while I'm running it locally.

Currently its executing sprocs through numerous spread out `SqlCommand`'s so I'd like to just get a list of every query that is ran.

Is there any sort of tool or configuration that I can setup to log this information?  Normally I would just use something like SQL Profiler but I'm looking for something to run from the WCF perspective since I'm hitting an Azure database and SQL Profilier won't work with Azure (afaik)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929586/sql-azure-profiling.

Comment: @Brent Yeah, I saw that, that's why I'm approaching this from the perspective of just logging everything going out of my WCF Service.  I'd like something sort of along the lines of the configuration that you can setup to log all of your WCF calls etc that your app makes

Comment: You might also try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx

Comment: Are you using an ORM?  I use NHibernate and it supports logging everything through log4net.

Comment: @Mike Nope, just straight `SqlCommand`s :-/  Yeah, I know EF and NHibernate have that, and I'm pretty sure L2S has something too.

Comment: Yes, The DataContext class from L2S has a Log Property for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built in way of logging all sql code when using SqlCommand/SqlConnection.

I found this article on msdn: [Data Access Tracing in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx) maybe it points you in the right direction.

A simpler but not very generic way i can imagine is to write a class that inherits from SqlCommand and delegates all methods to the real SqlCommand while adding some logging.

Answer (score 1):

Yea along the lines of what Jan said I'm not aware of just a generic logger with SQlCommand/SQLConnections you can plug into but if you are generating your SQLCommands from a standardized place you could make use of

[StatementCompletedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.statementcompleted%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

And from there pass the commands text to some sort of general logger like log4net/Console.Write/or something from the MS Ent Lib

Probably not the simple solution you were hoping for :-) Ideally there'd be some logging class you could register in the config file but I'm not aware of anything like that either :-/