# How to tell which stored procedures are executing with params on SQL Azure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, profiler

I have moved my website to SQL Azure and Azure Websites. I have a performance issue with certain stored procedures which are timing out from the UI. I need to capture the **exact** SQL call with parameters and execute this in a query window to diagnose the issue.

When running SQL locally I would just run SQL Profiler and capture the SQL traffic. In SQL Azure I cannot do this.

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

1. Running queries for DMV:

   http://www.developer.com/services/how-to-identify-performance-bottlenecks-on-azure-sql-database.html
   http://programming4.us/database/2716.aspx
   http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero/

   (This showed me the worst performing queries, but NOT the exact stored proc call when I hit the frontend)

2 Installed Glimpse and checking the SQL tab (I am running a DotNetNuke site and the code does not use the correct interface, so this did not show the SQL Server stored procedures being executed)

3. Fiddler (no SQL information in the HTTP call of course)
4. Azure "Manage Database" - this shows the slowest queries and is really useful, but NOT the currently incoming stored procedures
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benko/archive/2012/05/19/cloudtip-14-how-do-i-get-sql-profiler-info-from-sql-azure.aspx

My last resort is to copy the whole site and database locally and set it up, but it seems like such a simple requirement...

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929586/sql-azure-profiling

Answer (score 5):

There is a query you can run to get the last 500 queries run against a Windows Azure SQL Database, see below:

```
SELECT TOP 500 * 
FROM
(
    SELECT  [Last Execution Time] = last_execution_time,
            [Execution Count] = execution_count,
    [SQL Statement] = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING (s2. TEXT,statement_start_offset / 2+ 1 ,
    ( ( CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
    THEN ( LEN(CONVERT (NVARCHAR( MAX),s2 .TEXT)) * 2 )
                    ELSE statement_end_offset END )- statement_start_offset) / 2 +1)
                    ),
            [Stored Procedure Name] = COALESCE( OBJECT_NAME(s2 .objectid), 'Ad-Hoc Query'),
            [Last Elapsed Time] = s1.last_elapsed_time,
            [Minimum Elapsed Time] = s1.min_elapsed_time,
            [Maximum Elapsed Time] = s1.max_elapsed_time
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2 
) x
WHERE [SQL Statement] NOT LIKE '%SELECT TOP 500%' /* Exclude this query */
ORDER BY [Last Execution Time] DESC
```

Does this provide you with the parameters you need to see?